# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasterio.mask'

Tags: anaconda, modulenotfounderror, rasterio

Anaconda has stopped running rioxarray for some reason after working fine previously, and now when I try to import, it comes up with the error below.  I am running anaconda 2.4.2, rasterio 1.3.8 andrioxarray 0.15.0.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 4
      1 # !pip install rasterio
      2 # !pip install rioxarray
      3 import xarray as xr
----> 4 import rioxarray as rio
      5 from rasterio.plot import show
      6 from rasterio.windows import from_bounds

File ~\anaconda3\envs\envi5809\Lib\site-packages\rioxarray\__init__.py:5
      2 __author__ = """rioxarray Contributors"""
      3 import importlib.metadata
----> 5 import rioxarray.raster_array  # noqa
      6 import rioxarray.raster_dataset  # noqa
      7 from rioxarray._io import open_rasterio

File ~\anaconda3\envs\envi5809\Lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_array.py:20
     18 import numpy
     19 import rasterio
---> 20 import rasterio.mask
     21 import rasterio.warp
     22 import xarray

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasterio.mask'
```

I've tried !pip install for both rasterio and rioxarray and creating new environments but none of this is working and i still get the same error message.

I've also tried installing osgeo in case it was a gdal issue form this link but it doesnt seem to have done anything.
https://www.osgeo.org/projects/osgeo4w/

Any help is appreciated, Thank you